# RestSharp not giving response in Xamarin.Android but giving response in command line in c#

Tags: c#, xamarin.android

Restsharp is not giving response in Xamarin.Android but working perfact in c# CommandLine console app.

```
var client = new RestClient("https://shotlo.com/api");
var request = new RestRequest("getProfile", Method.POST);
request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
request.AddParameter("token", "00");
request.AddParameter("userId", "00");
IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
var content = response.Content;
```

Comment: Notice that Xamarin.Android is based on Mono and ConsoleApplication is based on "real" .Net. Check if Restsharp supports Mono.

Comment: yes it supports mono

Comment: Thanks for this help. But actual error was "System.Net.WebException : Send Failure. Error Writing Headers" that was resolved by adding "ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += (sender, cert, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true;"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a version of [RestSharp](https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/blob/master/releasenotes.markdown) that should work 105.2.2, if you are on monoandroid10?

Is the code in a PCL or an actual Xamarin.Android library? If it is not in a PCL, are you developing an Android only app? Will it always be Android only? If not I'd recommend putting code like this into a PCL so you can re-use it from your Android or iOS implementations (kinda the point of using Xamarin?).

I'd also question the need for what is essentially a wrapper. I like RestSharp and use it myself but in Xamarin projects I just use [System.Net.WebRequest](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest(v=vs.110).aspx) (from inside a PCL). If you can get RestSharp working then great, go for it, otherwise drop back to WebRequest.

Start by creating the request:

```
var request = WebRequest.CreateHttp(url);
request.Method = method;
request.ContentType = contentType;

await AddBodyToRequest(data, request);
// add your headers here
```

Add the body (unedited):

```
        protected static async Task AddBodyToRequest(byte[] data, WebRequest request)
    {
        Logger.Debug("AddBodyToRequest: {0}", request.ContentType);
        var uri = request.RequestUri.AbsoluteUri;
        try
        {
            using (Stream stream = await Task<Stream>.Factory.FromAsync(request.BeginGetRequestStream, request.EndGetRequestStream, null))
            {
                stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Logger.Info(string.Format("[{0}] {1}. AddBodyToRequest [{2}]"
                , ex.GetType().Name, ex.Message, uri));
        }
    }
```

Then send using something like:

```
    using (var response = await request.GetResponseAsync(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(timeout)))
{
    try
    {
        return new ServiceCallResult<TR>(response);
```

You can just return the response, personally I prefer to wrap the response (ServiceCallResult is a customer wrapper)...

I also check I 'can send' before trying...essentially checking the device still has a connection, not necessary but given you're on a device it's generally a good ideal (IMHO).

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for this help. But actual error was "System.Net.WebException : Send Failure. Error Writing Headers" that was resolved by adding "ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += (sender, cert, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true;"